# intensity meter is hanging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, memory-leaks

I have made a gauge which is showing maximum intensity coming in camera. For making gauge I have first put a dialer in background of a panel and then drawing needle on a pictureBox which is on that panel and pictureBox having transparent background.

My code is as follows...

```
private: System::Void FocusExposure_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 th = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this,&FocusExposure::UpdateIntensity)); 
                th->Start();            
             }

void UpdateIntensity()
     {
         int intensity=0;
        Intensity_Values data;
         while(1)
         {
         data = ReadImage(cameraBuffer);
                 if(count == 1)
                 {
                     count++;
                    label14->Text =  Convert::ToString(data.Max);
                 }
             label7->Text =  Convert::ToString(data.Max);
             label8->Text =  Convert::ToString(data.Min);
             label9->Text =  Convert::ToString(data.Avg);
             label10->Text =  Convert::ToString(data.Max_Min);
            draw_Intens( data.Max);
         }
     }
private: void draw_Intens(int intensity)
             {

                 this->pictureBox1->Refresh();
                 double const PI = 3.14159265358979323;
                 float degree=angle_array[intensity]*PI/180;
                 circumPoint xy= cordinate_point(degree);

                 Graphics ^ graphics = pictureBox1->CreateGraphics(); 
                 SolidBrush^ shadowBrush = gcnew SolidBrush( Color::Blue );
                     Pen^ penCurrent = gcnew Pen(Color::Blue,3);
                                    graphics->FillEllipse(shadowBrush, 93, 93,14, 14);
                                    graphics->DrawLine(penCurrent, Point(100, 100), Point(xy.x, xy.y));
                                    delete penCurrent;
                                    delete shadowBrush;
                                    delete graphics;
            }
circumPoint cordinate_point(float degree)
         { 
             circumPoint pointxy;
             pointxy.x =  100+redius * cos(degree);
             pointxy.y =  100+redius * sin(degree);
             return pointxy;
         }
```

**angle_array** is a array `double angle_array[]={126.000000,126.070313,126.140625,...,414.000000}` having 4097 angle value using these value needle will rotate.

**ReadImage(cameraBuffer)** is a function with is returning
Max,
Min,
Avg,
Max_Min
intensity values.

**Intensity_Values** is a structure of Max Min Avg Max_Min values.

```
typedef struct {
   int  Max;
   int  Min;
   int  Avg;
   int Max_Min;
} Intensity_Values;
```

My gauge is like this...

[image]

Left side having min intensity 0 and Right side having Max intensity value 4096.

**Now My problem is that when I am running my application it starts and after 2 3 seconds it hangs or can say stops working. I think problem may be memory leak but I am not getting where is the problem.**

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.